# Merge sequential objects in single array based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'd like to merge sequential objects of data in an array based on conditions. I have an itinerary array where each object is a leg of that trip. Consider the following examples:

Trip 1: `WALK - WALK - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK
                                       ^ short transfer`

Trip 2: `WALK - WALK - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - VEHICLE`

Trip 3: `WALK - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - WALK`

---

What I'd like to do is to merge the `WALK` legs if they're sequential (right after each other) into one `WALK` leg covering the merged parts, see below:

Trip 1: `WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK
                         ^ short transfer`

Trip 2: `WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - VEHICLE`

Trip 3: `WALK - VEHICLE - WALK`

---

Each leg object looks something like this:

```
{
    mode: 'WALK', // or VEHICLE
    to: { ... },
    from: { ... }
}
```

---

I've tried using `.reduce()` and with help from its current index feature group the different parts together, with no success. I don't even know if it's the right function to use.

```js
const oldTrip = [
 { mode: 'WALK' },
 { mode: 'WALK' },
 { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
 { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
 { mode: 'WALK' }
];

let previousWalk = false;
const newTrip = oldTrip.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
  if (cur.mode === 'VEHICLE') previousWalk = false;
  else {
    if (previousWalk) {
      
    }
    previousWalk = true;
  }
  return acc;
});
```

Any help or push in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56632109/edit) then the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I've updated my post, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#reduce` will return you one value.

Use `Array#filter` instead by comparing the last iterated value to the current one.

```js
const steps = [
  { mode: 'WALK' },
  { mode: 'WALK' },
  { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
  { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
  { mode: 'WALK' },
  { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
  { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
  { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
  { mode: 'WALK' },
  { mode: 'WALK' },
  { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
  { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
  { mode: 'WALK' }
];

console.log(

steps.filter((s, i, self) => (
  !self[i + 1]
    || s.mode === 'VEHICLE'
    || self[i + 1].mode !== s.mode
  ))

);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reduce() I use filter() with an index, thankfully we can't run into an OutOfBound like this. We only check for repetitions when we have a "WALK" as current element. I added a fourth example to show that non-walk repetitions don't get filtered.

```js
function filterRepWalk(a) {
  return a.filter((v,i) => v != "WALK" || v != a[i-1]);
}

console.log(filterRepWalk(["WALK", "WALK", "WALK", "VEHICLE", "WALK",  "VEHICLE", "WALK"]));
console.log(filterRepWalk(["WALK", "WALK", "WALK", "VEHICLE", "WALK", "WALK", "VEHICLE", "WALK", "VEHICLE"]));
console.log(filterRepWalk(["WALK", "WALK", "VEHICLE", "WALK", "WALK"]));
console.log(filterRepWalk(["WALK", "WALK", "WALK", "VEHICLE", "WALK", "WALK", "VEHICLE", "WALK", "VEHICLE", "VEHICLE"]));
```

And for doing the same on an object the following works:

```
function filterRepWalk(a) {
  return a.filter((v,i) => (!a[i-1] || (v.mode != a[i-1].mode)) || v.mode != "WALK");
}
```

Comment: The last test is wrong, there are two consecutive `VEHICLE` at the end.

Comment: He stated he wants to merge the WALK parts but didn't say he wants to merge the other parts too. I explicitly added the condition to only merge WALK sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure at the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array parameter and get a concise solution like this:

```js
let filter = (arr, str) => arr.filter((x,i,{[i-1]:k}) => x != str || x != k)

console.log(filter(["WALK", "WALK", "VEHICLE"], 'WALK'));
console.log(filter(["VEHICLE", "VEHICLE", "WALK"], 'VEHICLE'));
```

You can also pass now any one of the strings you want to be "merged".

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach which does utilize `Array.prototype.reduce` like you mentioned:

```js
const getDirections = str => {
  //Split the string into an array and remove the whitespace
  const data = str.split('-').map(el => el.replace(/\s/g, ''));

  //Add to the accumulator if the prior element is different
  return data.reduce((accum, el, idx, arr) => {
    if (el !== accum[accum.length - 1]) {
      accum.push(el);
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);
}


const directions = getDirections("WALK - WALK - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - WALK - VEHICLE - WALK - VEHICLE");

console.log(directions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const oldTrip = [
    { mode: 'WALK' },
    { mode: 'WALK' },
    { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
    { mode: 'VEHICLE' },
    { mode: 'WALK' }
];

const newTrip = oldTrip.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.mode === 'WALK' && acc.length && acc[acc.length - 1].mode === 'WALK') {
        return acc;
    }
    acc.push(cur);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newTrip);
```